# Android SQLite Performance: Multiple selects in single query Vs single select in multiple queries?

Tags: android, sqlite, query-performance, sqlperformance

Performance wise, which one is better (for a single table) ?:

1. Multiple select in single query or
2. Single select in multiple queries?

Example:

```
/*table schema*/
create table ACTIVITY_TABLE (
ID integer primary key autoincrement,
INTERVAL_ID integer not null, 
ACTIVITY_TYPE text , 
WIFI_LIST text, 
COUNT integer not null );



/*Multipe selects in single query*/
select * from 
    (select sum(COUNT)/60 as Physical from ACTIVITY_TABLE where  INTERVAL_ID >=1  and  INTERVAL_ID <=3 and (ACTIVITY_TYPE="Still" or ACTIVITY_TYPE = "Walking" or ACTIVITY_TYPE = "Running"  ) ),
    (select sum(COUNT)/60 as vehicular from ACTIVITY_TABLE where  INTERVAL_ID >=1  and  INTERVAL_ID <=3 and (ACTIVITY_TYPE="InVehicle" ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you can modify the query in the following way which will be much more efficient, I didn't tested the query.

```
select
sum(case when activitytype='walking' or activitytype='still' or activitytype='running' then COUNT else 0 end )/60 as physical,

sum(case when activitytype='InVehicle' then COUNT else 0 end)/60 as vehicular

from

activity_table

where interval_id>=1 and interval_id<=3
```

Comment: thanks @Mohanraja, but your query doesn't give me expected result

Comment: @ctu i guess i missed COUNT & (/60) part, I will edit that part, try it now

Comment: now the query gives expected result. it'll be nice to have a script or code to check the performance of both queries. I 'll make some googling maybe i can find some sqlite query performance tester , because right now both queries(yours and mine) return the result in 1ms hence i cant really tell which one is better. Thanks for your input though:)